# How To Make Layout (Not Activity Layout, Fragment) using Anko(DSL)?

Tags: android, layout, kotlin, dsl, anko

I know how to make Activity's Layout using an extended AnkoComponent class
and Fragment using onCreateView method

Then, I need layouts will be included in Fragment.
But I don't know how to make layouts using Anko Layout

this is my example Fragment

```
class ExampleFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, 
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val ui = UI {
            verticalLayout {
                include(id1 < ----??)
                include(id2 < ----??)
            }
        }
    return ui.view
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make a layout using Anko?

Answer (score 0):

You can include XML layouts with the `include` function, like so:

```
include<View>(R.layout.something)
```

See the docs for more details [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Layouts#include-tag).

Comment: Is there any way to include views using DSL instead of XML?